# All values of boolean-triple

Tags: java

Let `a,b,c` be a boolean value. I need to print all values of expression `a && b && c`. I'm writing the class

```
public class BooleanTriple{
    private boolean a,b,c;
    public BooleanTriple(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c){ this.a =a; this.b=b; this.c=c;}

    /**
    *Increments the value of triple with lexicographical ordering
    */
    public void incr(){
        if (!a) a=true;
        else if(!b){
            a= false;
            b= true;
        else if (!c){
            a= false;        
            b= false;
            c=true;  
        }
    }
    public boolean logProduct(){ return a && b && c;}
}
```

And Main class:

```
public class Main{
    BooleanTriple bTriple = new BooleanTriple(false,false,false);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
            System.out.println(bTriple.logProduct());
            bTriple.incr();
        }
    }
}
```

But i think, that it's bad implementation. Can you correct me?

Comment: `Does it work?`

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do... but is your program working correctly...?

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, can it implements more generally?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Yes, there definitely exists an implementation for this, given an arbitrary number of booleans

Comment: @DmitryFucintv notice that in general, the first boolean that is false, you set to true, and all before it to false. This is easily generalised.

Comment: By the way, I might add `if(a && b && c) return (a && b && c)` and skip out of the entire `if else` structure since the `if else` structure only handles cases where any of them are false.

Comment: @nhgrif Yeah, the idea is that he is only looping it 8 (2^3, which is also easily generalised) times.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint. Think of a && b && c as a 3 digit binary number

So all possibles values will be:

```
a | b | c
0 | 0 | 0
0 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | 0
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 0
1 | 1 | 1
```

As you can see, you want to flip c every time and check the value of a and b to determine what they will be. b will change any time c is 1 and a will change any time b and c are 1. This should be enough to give you a better implementation.

Comment: You could also loop between 0 and 7. a will be `(i%8)/4`. b will be `(i%4)/2`. And c will be `(i%2)/1` :)

Comment: I never have thought about it like that. That's a really smart and simple way to do it.

Comment: Yep, it also allows you to jump to an arbitrary point in the ordering, and not depend on the previous iteration

Answer (score 1):

I find recursive approach to be a better one, since you can easily adapt it for an arbitrary number of boolean variables. Here's a quick implementation just to give you an idea:

```
public class Triple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> combinations = new HashSet<>();
        generateCombinations("", combinations);
        System.out.println(combinations); // [010, 110, 111, 011, 000, 101, 001, 100]
        for (String combination : combinations)
            logProduct(combination);
    }

    private static void generateCombinations(String prefix, Set<String> dest) {
        if (prefix.length() == 3) {
            dest.add(prefix);
        } else {
            generateCombinations(prefix + "0", dest);
            generateCombinations(prefix + "1", dest);
        }
    }

    private static void logProduct(String input) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        boolean result = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            boolean next = input.charAt(i) != '0';
            result &= next;
            output.append(next);
            if (i != input.length() - 1)
                output.append(" && ");
            else
                output.append(" = ").append(result);
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```

And the output sample is: `true && true && false = false`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple version done in one loop. I developed this independently of @Cruncher's comment, but please give him credit also.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean a = false;
    boolean b = false;
    boolean c = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        c = !c;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            b = !b;
        if (i % 4 == 0)
            a = !a;
        System.out.println("A: " + a + ", B: " + b + ", C: " + c + " | value: " + (a && b && c));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to "increment the boolean values" similar to binary values this might help you:

```
public class dummy1 {

static BooleanTriple bTriple = new BooleanTriple(false, false, false);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " => " + bTriple.logProduct());
        bTriple.incr();
    }
}
}

class BooleanTriple {

private int value;

public BooleanTriple(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    value = (a ? 1 : 0) + (b ? 2 : 0) + (c ? 4 : 0);
}

public void incr() {
    //if (value < 7) // if the increment should not "loop"
    value = ++value & 7;
}

public boolean logProduct() {
    return value == 0b111; // 7
}
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `value = ++value & 7;`? This will cause 7 to still be 7 after incrementing. Did you mean `value = ++value % 7;`? By the way, using `++value` in an assignment statement to `value` is rather obtuse. I would just use `value+1`.

Comment: @Cruncher: The " & 7" should have been removed when i added the comment in the line above - since the questioner only mentioned 3 bool vars i assumed that is the "default" he meant. About the "++value": first the right side of equal sign is evaluated and then the result is assigned to left side of "=". So it is no error and incrementing is faster and results in shorter code than adding 1.

Comment: It's no error, but it's a little bit confusing. It's also not faster. This is what is happening. You are adding 1 to value. Assigning it to value, Using that value in the expression `value & 7` and then assigning the result to value. You assign to value twice here. (I don't know exactly how it translates to bytecote, my guess is that the compiler actually optimizes it to `value+1`)

Comment: I guess we both do not have debugged the resulting code on assembler level. But as i know from my "assembler times" incrementing a value (by one) is just a single machine code instruction while an addition of an value needs to load the value (1), add it and store the result (3 opcodes). Anyway, as long as we agree that it is not an error we should close discussion about that.

Comment: @Michael Besteck: your code still needs to load and store the value as you still have an assignment of the form `value=expression`. If you admit that you don’t have a clue about the resulting code, then don’t add these “optimizations” to your code.

Comment: @Holger: I have written a sort of test case for the problem
(http://system33.de/temp/TestExecutionSpeed.java). That shows that my increment version has an execution time of 289820ms while the "x+1" version has an execution time of 291514ms for 10^11 executions. For that high number of executions both methods can be taken as effectively equal in execution time (mine seems faster). The level on which you are arguing does not take CPU architecture, microcode execution, cache effects, compiler optimization et. al. into account. You are thinking not on a real but on an only theoretical level.

Comment: You are talking about performance but use constructs like `(new Date()).getTime()` instead of `System.nanoTime()`? I have the strong feeling that you optimize at the wrong places of your code… But anyway, I’m not talking about theoretical things, I *know* that there is no such thing than a special increment instruction for fields in Java bytecode (despite to local variables). Just disassemble the class file if you don’t believe it, both methods do the same besides the fact that the `++` creates an additional store operation. So it’s not surprising that your version is *slower* in most setups.

Answer (score 0):

Why not iterate over the boolean values `true` and `false` like this?

```
        final boolean[] bools=new boolean[]{false,true};
        for (boolean a:bools)
         {
         for (boolean b:bools)
         {
            for (boolean c:bools)
         {
             System.out.println("a: "+a+" b: "+b+" c: "+c+": => "+(a && b && c));

         }

         }  

         }
```

Output will be:

> a: false b: false c: false: => false
>
> a: false b: false c: true:  => false
>
> a: false b: true c: false:  => false
>
> a: false b: true c: true:   => false
>
> a: true b: false c: false:  => false
>
> a: true b: false c: true:   => false
>
> a: true b: true c: false:   => false
>
> a: true b: true c: true:    => true

Comment: Because it is not a very flexible way of doing it. Imagine you would want to change to using 6 bools instead, you would have to add 3 more for-loops.